# In D, how to pass an empty string? (to gtkD)

Tags: gtk, d, string, gtkd

Using D1 with phobos

I have a text entry field, instance of `gtk.Entry.Entry`,

calling `setText("")` raises a run time error

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed
```

Why? It seems to be a problem with D, I tried this:

```
string empty = "";
assert (empty != null);
my_entry.setText(empty)
```

The program terminated as the assertion failed.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think D really differentiates between "empty string" and "null string". A cheap workaround would be setText(" ").

[edit] Nevermind that. It's a bug in gtkD. in trunk/src/glib/Str.d (thanks wm4 for finding it), change line 147 to return ""; (remove the .dup).

Answer (score 3):

You should write assert(empty !is null) instead of assert(empty != null)

Answer (score 1):

I used `"\0"` and it seemed to work,

I don't know if any invisible character got into the text field, but this is based on the assumption that an empty string in C is just `\0`